# Anti-virus detection of function

Tags: vb.net

I recently wrote an program that includes this function :

```
Private Declare Function rrr Lib "UsEr32" Alias "CallWindowProcA" (ByVal uu As Long, ByVal tt As Long, ByVal ii As Long, ByVal oo As Long, ByVal ll As Long) As Long
```

this is the shot :

[image: shot]

In conclusion, my anti-virus detect virus from the source of my program.

How can i solve it?

Comment: Did it say something like "Virus detected" or are you concluding that since it denied access to your program?

Comment: i add screen shot @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ

Comment: That PInvoke isnt correct.  That message seems more like it doesnt like something the app does - do you use CodeDom or extract something from resources to disk?

Comment: @Plutonix that PInvoke signature is correct. For `CallWindowProcA` it is `Public Declare Function CallWindowProc Lib "user32.dll" Alias "CallWindowProcA" (ByVal lpPrevWndFunc As Long, ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal Msg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Long) As Long`. **"That PInvoke isnt correct"** could you please add *why* it is not correct?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633571(v=vs.85).aspx andalso http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/CallWindowProc.html

Comment: @Plutonix that is C++ mind translating that? Each param is a `long` datatype and take 5 params of which he is. One thing to keep in mind is we don't know if he is indeed passing the right values to each. Yes some have the `IntPtr` type, but then again that can be sent as a long..

Comment: @Codexer - `Long` seems to be an odd choice for `wParam` and `lParam`.    It seems like they should be `Integer` or at `IntPtr`.  That seems more like a VB6 signature.  pinvoke.net show this:  <DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Private Shared Function CallWindowProc(lpPrevWndFunc As WndProcDelegate, hWnd As IntPtr, Msg As UInteger, wParam As IntPtr, lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr
End Function

Answer (score 1):

> **my anti-virus detect virus from the source of my program**

In conclusion, it is doing it's job then (**signature detection**). The reason the scanner picked it up is because of the Windows API call to `User32` which in the long wrong when used in a bad way can create some havoc on the system. The only two option's I could see doing is...

1. Create a patch to prevent the AV from hooking onto that API (**not very easy**).
2. Exclude this program so the scanner or real-time protection doesn't look at it. (**Better Option**)

In your AV there should be a way to exclude this. Try `System Scanner → Scan → Exception` and or `Real-Time Protection → Scan → Exception`.

**On another Note:** if the application is not signed some AV will pick this up as what they call as a `Dropper` which usually drop things onto your system and can cause a mess. The `.gen` at the end is for generic trojan as it can't actually be classified or hasn't been classified yet with the AV software. That is why you usually can report some applications and software as safe that way they can exclude these from the scan's.